# how to add a jquery script tag in pug?

Tags: jquery, pug

Not sure about it failed at adding script tag or it's because the jquery library. But it failed when I aa the jquery script tag to my pug file. It works perfectly without the script tag.

```
html
head
    title !{comp}
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css')
script(src='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js')
body
    table
        tr
            th Session
            th Num.
            th Couple
            th Age
            th Division
            th Dance Studio
            th Heat
        each event in events    
            tr
                td=event.Session
                td=event.CoupleID
                td=event.Couple
                td=event.Age
                td=event.Division
                td=event.DanceStudio
                td=event.Heat
```

I got a 404 not found after I add the jquery script tag and I'm not sure why.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Is your file really indented exactly like that?  If so, the script tag needs to be indented at exactly the same depth as the link tag right above it.  That would cause your error.

Comment: I have voted to close this question as it was due to a "simple typographical error", this issue would be difficult for others to replicate and would provide little value to future users.

Answer (score 0):

Your `script` tag is **between** the `head` tag and the `body` tag, which is not valid HTML.

The standard place to put scripts is **in** the body tag, at the end of it, after the visible UI tags.

Answer (score -2):

Found out why. I forget to set the static for express.